# How to prove the Taylor series converges for a smooth function with nonnegative derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

> Suppose $f\in C^{\infty}[a,b]$, and for any $n\geq 1$, $f^{(n)}(x)$ is non-negative. Prove that
> $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n\,,\, \forall x\in [a,b]\,. $$
> Hint: using $R_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\int_a^x f^{(n+1)}(t) (t-a)^n dt $ and $f^{(n)}(x)$ is increasing.

I have tried in the following way:
$$\begin{aligned}
R_n(x)&=\frac{1}{n!}\int_a^x f^{(n+1)}(t) (t-a)^n dt \\&= \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n+1)}(\xi) \int_a^x  (t-a)^n dt\\&\leq \frac{f^{(n+1)}(b)}{(n+1)!} (b-a)^{n+1}.
\end{aligned}$$
But I don’t know how to prove last step, which is $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(b)}{(n+1)!} (b-a)^{n+1} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Or there is another method to solve this problem, looking forward to your answers! Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946892/taylor-series-of-infinitely-differentiable-function-with-nonnegative-derivatives

Comment: Thank you! I’m so foolish! This question is so easy!

Answer (score 0):

Since fⁿ⁺¹(b) constant, if (b-a)$\le$ 1 then (b-a)ⁿ⁺¹/(n+1)! goes to 0 as n tend to ∞ automatically.
But if (b-a)>1 then take aₙ=(b-a)ⁿ⁺¹/(n+1)!
Now since $\lim_{n\to ∞}$ aₙ₊₁/aₙ=$\lim_{n\to ∞}$ (b-a)/(n+2)=0 < 1,( the property : {aₙ} be a sequence of positive real numbers then if $\lim_{n\to ∞}$ aₙ₊₁/aₙ<1 then $\lim_{n\to ∞}$ aₙ = 0 and if $\lim_{n\to ∞}$ aₙ₊₁/aₙ>1 then $\lim_{n\to ∞}$ aₙ tends to ∞).
$\lim_{n\to ∞}$ aₙ = 0 , as required.