# $n$th derivative is non-negative for $n=0,1,2,...$, then Taylor series converge, and is exactly $f(x)$ everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Try to prove, if $$f^{(n)}(x)\geq 0,\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\;\forall n=0,1,2,...$$ then the Taylor series at the point $0$ converges everywhere, **and it's exactly $f(x)$**, i.e.
> $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n,\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$$

I know it is sufficient, and necessary, to prove,
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}{R_n(f,x)}=0\iff\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}{\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^n}=0$$
but I dont know any methods to estimate the value of the $n$th derivative. Can you help me? Thanks!

***Update:***

Notice: The Taylor series converges everywhere (proved in another similar problem: [Taylor series of Infinitely differentiable function with nonnegative derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946892/taylor-series-of-infinitely-differentiable-function-with-nonnegative-derivatives)), but it's interesting that it is equal to $f(x)$.

It's possible to prove the formula where $x<0$: consider $$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}{\left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\right|}\leq\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}{\left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{(n+1)!}\right||x|^{n+1}}=0.$$

...And I have an idea !

For $x_0>0:$consider
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k}{k!}-f(x)}$$
and $g(2x_0)$.

Comment: it's easy to prove the formula where x<0

Comment: Please show that and why the Taylor series converges when the above condition holds ! This is far from obvious !

Comment: @Peter This question was previously considered to be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/946892 where the convergence is proved. Hence, the OP knows how to prove the convergence. The question is the equaility of $f$ and the Maclaurin series, which is not discussed in the "duplicate".

Comment: @Gary Nevertheless this partial result should be posted because someone might be able to extend it to a proof of the new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One *messy* solution.

**Step 1:**

Notice $\forall n=0,1,2,...,f^{(n)}(x)$ is **non-decreasing**.

Consider
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{f^{(k)}{(0)}}{k!}x^k}-f(x)$$
we have
$$g^{(n+1)}(x)=-f(x)\leq0$$
then $g^{(n)}(x)$ is non-increasing,and
$$\forall x\geq 0,g^{(n)}(x)\leq g^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(0)-f^{(n)}(0)=0$$
this means $g^{(n-1)}(x)$ is non-increasing,and
$$\forall x\geq 0,g^{(n-1)}(x)\leq g^{(n-1)}(0)=f^{(n-1)}(0)+\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x}{1}-f^{(n-1)}(x)\Bigg|_{x=0}=0$$
and inductively,we have
$\forall k=n,n-1,...,0,g^{(k)}(x)$ is non-increasing on $[0,+\infty)$

which means,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{f^{(k)}{(0)}}{k!}x^k}\leq f(x),\forall x\geq 0$$
so $\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty}{\frac{f^{(k)}(0)x^{k}}{k!}}=0$(all terms are non-nagative and sum is bounded)

and $\forall x<0$,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\left|{\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}\right|\leq\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}{\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(0)||x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}=0$$

**Step 2:**

for $x_0 >0$,consider
$$h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{f^{(k)}{(x_0)}}{k!}(x-x_0)^k}-f(x)$$
we still have(method is the same)
$\forall k=n,n-1,...,0,h^{(k)}(x)$ is non-increasing on $[x_0,+\infty)$

which means,
$$h(2x_0)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{f^{(k)}{(x_0)}}{k!}(2x_0-x_0)^k}- f(2x_0)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{f^{(k)}{(x_0)}}{k!}x_0^k}-f(2x_0)\leq 0,\forall x\geq x_0$$
so $\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty}{\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)x_0^{k}}{k!}}=0$(all terms are non-nagative and sum is bounded)

and $\forall x_0>0$,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\left|{\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)x_0^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}\right|\leq\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}{\frac{f^{(n+1)}(x_0)x_0^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}=0$$